# activeMQ activemq-admin

Tags: activemq-classic, admin

how to use "activemq-admin" to view the list of queues;  number of messages in the queue;

I read through the tutorial :   http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html

didn't find a working solution...

and my web console on the slave machine does not work...  the web console seems always go with the master machine  (in the master/slave structure)

I just want to test that  if I send messages into queues on master,  slave could update.

so I am trying to use activemq-admin.

Comment: You can use hawtio as a web console that allows to remote connect to any ActiveMQ broker, whether its a master or slave: http://hawt.io/

Comment: To use the activemq-admin command you need to pass in a lot of options to tell it to connect to the remote broker etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that Slave is waiting to get a lock to the DB (Kahadb by default) , you will not be able to check the slave , bring down the master and now the slave will become the master broker and you should be able to see all the queues and messages dropped in them (assuming you are using persistence)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMX, web console or programatically, as you can find [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-topics-and-queues-in-a-broker.html). 
 The easiest solution, I think, is to use web console like [here](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html).
 
I can't understand why isn't accessible the web console. Check for ActiveMQ config xml.
Also you can connect via JMX like:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Go [here](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) for more information.